# Select a single row with a given date using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database

```
Table1
___________________
id    Date
1     2016/1/05
2     2012/5/09
3     2010/6/23
4     2009/7/18
5     2002/2/13
```

Trying to write a SQL Query that returns an id using a given date.

If the date is not in the table it should return the closest date to the given date.

So....if the input date is 1/2/2016 it would return id 1 because this is the closest match

If the input date is 2/12/2003 it would return id 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

----Edited---

use 'abs' to get "closest" number.

```
declare @t1 as table (id int,date datetime)
insert into @t1 select 1,'2016/1/05'
insert into @t1 select 2,'2012/5/09'
insert into @t1 select 3,'2010/6/23'
insert into @t1 select 4,'2009/7/18'
insert into @t1 select 5,'2002/2/13'

declare @inputDate datetime = '2003/2/12'
select top 1.id from @t1 order by abs(datediff(dd,date,@inputDate))

set @inputDate = '2016/1/02'
select top 1.id from @t1 order by abs(datediff(dd,date,@inputDate))
```

Comment: won't work, the date closest can be greater as well.You would have to get two dates, one greater and one lesser and then compare those two to see which is the closest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pseudo code something like this...

```
select id,date,min(days_cnt)
(Select id , date,(date-input_date) as days_cnt from table) 
where days_cnt > 0
```